# ElasticSearch bool query with slop, how to achieve?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query where I need to find N number of words AND the document must also match a regular expression string.  I have that working but I also have the requirement that the terms must be within 3 words of each other, in Elastic syntax slop:3.  The problem is slop isn't allowed on a bool query.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "explain": true,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "*"
    ],
    "excludes": [
      "doctext"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "doctext": {
              "query": "value1 value2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "doctext": {
              "value": "[0-9]{3}"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `match` query with `match_phrase` and add a `slop` to it e.g.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "explain": true,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
      "doctext"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "doctext": {
              "query": "value1 value2",
              "slop": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "doctext": {
              "value": "[0-9]{3}"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  This is close but the slop value only applies to the "match_phrase" values and not the regexp value. I am trying to utilize slop across both sets of search criteria.

Comment: @KevinTracey regexp query does not accept a slop parameter

Comment: I was able to solve it thanks to help from two posters on Elastic's message board.  Using span_near we were able to get to work:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/best-practice-to-search-for-a-regular-expression-next-to-a-list-of-terms/132383/5

Comment: Span queries are a good tool for solving term proximity queries